# SQL Query returns more

Tags: sql

I'm having a bit of a problem with a SQL Query that returns too many results. I'm fairly new to SQL so please bear with me.

Please see the following:

[Table Structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jEvy.jpg)

The Query that I use looks like:

```
    SELECT TABLE_B.*
    FROM 
        TABLE_A
    JOIN
        TABLE_B
    ON
        TABLE_A.COMMON_ID=TABLE_B.COMMON_ID
        AND TABLE_A.SEQ_3C=TABLE_B.SEQ_3C
    JOIN
        TABLE_C
    ON
        TABLE_A.COMMON_ID=TABLE_C.EMPLID
WHERE
        TABLE_B.ITEM_STATUS<>'C'
    and TABLE_A.CHECKLIST_STATUS='I'
    and TABLE_A.ADMIN_FUNCTION='ADMA'
    and TABLE_A.CHECKLIST_CD='APPL'
    and TABLE_A.COMMON_ID = '123456789'
    and TABLE_C.ADMIT_TERM='2171'
    and TABLE_C.INSTITUTION='SOMEWHERE'
```

I just want the results from Table_B and not what it's giving me.
Please explain this to me as I have spent 3 days on it non-stop.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't tag a lots of products not involved. You can put one of them back, the one you're using.

Comment: Please post you table structure and data as formatted text, so that people can easily create a test case and help you. You can have a look at [mcve]

Comment: It's not possible that it's giving you columns from Table_A or Table_C in the results, so please explain what you mean by "not what it's giving me".

Comment: Sorry about that I will try to do it quickly...

Comment: It's returning Table_B 3 times

Comment: @XantorAmnobius Use "select distinct". The duplicates are due to multiple matches on the joins (ie, multiple entries in the other tables).

Comment: Ha! It worked - brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: Please answer so that I may mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want data from TABLE_B? Then select from it only and have the conditions on the other tables in your where clause.

The inner joins on the other tables serve as existence tests, I assume? Don't do that. You'd only multiply your records, just as you are doing now, only to have to dismiss duplicates later. That can cause bad performance on large tables and errors in more complicated queries. Use `EXISTS` or `IN` instead.

```
select *
from table_b
where item_status <> 'C'
and (common_id, seq_3c) in
(
  select common_id, seq_3c 
  from table_a
  where checklist_status = 'I'
    and admin_function = 'ADMA'
    and checklist_cd = 'APPL'
)
and common_id in
(
  select EMPLID
  from table_c
  where admit_term = '2171'
    and institution = 'SOMEWHERE'
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will adjust my query accordingly. I figured it might cause performance issues especially on large databases. Seeing that I've only worked with SQL for about a week I'm not sure of all the "Best Practices" - Thanks a million!

Comment: I take it that I can use COUNT with the IN - in a similar fashion?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. `COUNT` and `IN` are two very different things. You use `IN` in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause to check whether a value or a tuple exists in a set. `COUNT` is used to count within a range of rows. You can use `COUNT` in the query that uses `IN`, e.g. replace `*` with `count(*)` in your query. And you can use it in the `IN` clause such as `where 1 in (select count(*) from x group by y)`. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_B.*
    FROM 
        TABLE_A
    JOIN
        TABLE_B
    ON
        TABLE_A.COMMON_ID=TABLE_B.COMMON_ID
        AND TABLE_A.SEQ_3C=TABLE_B.SEQ_3C
    JOIN
        TABLE_C
    ON
        TABLE_A.COMMON_ID=TABLE_C.EMPLID
WHERE
        TABLE_B.ITEM_STATUS<>'C'
    and TABLE_A.CHECKLIST_STATUS='I'
    and TABLE_A.ADMIN_FUNCTION='ADMA'
    and TABLE_A.CHECKLIST_CD='APPL'
    and TABLE_A.COMMON_ID = '123456789'
    and TABLE_C.ADMIT_TERM='2171'
    and TABLE_C.INSTITUTION='SOMEWHERE'
```

Comment: This will probably work, but when one needs to add DISTINCT that is often an indication the solution is inefficient to begin with. The OP probably needs an IN condition somewhere, not a join.

Comment: @mathguy: I agree 100%.

Comment: Could you give an example of this?

Comment: In addition, this may remove duplicates from table B even if they exist beforehand. (If table B has no duplicate rows, this is not a problem, but if it does, it is.)

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to understand without looking at all your tables and output.

Suppose you join two tables, `A` and `B`, on a column `id`. You only want the columns from table `B`, and in table `B` the `id' column is a unique identifier.

Even so, if in table `A` an `id` (the same `id`) appears five times, the join will have five rows for that `id`. Then you just select the columns from table `B`, so it will look like you got the same row five different times.

Perhaps you don't really need a join? What is your underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I come from a programming background and in terms of programming it could be expressed as: if a=b and b=c then return b so that you only get the items from b. So in actual fact I'm looking for If statements in SQL

Comment: @XantorAmnobius - then you need an `IN` condition, not a join. If the same `id` (in my example) exists in table `A` once or one thousand times makes no difference to you. If the DISTINCT solution works fine for you, no need to change your code, but if you run into performance problems you should change it. (For example, the DISTINCT solution may work in testing, but take too long in production.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without more information about why you're executing these joins. I can explain why you're getting the results you're getting, and hopefully that will allow you to solve the problem yourself.

You start, in your `FROM` clause, with table A. You join this table with table B on matching `COMMON_ID`, which, based on the tables you provide, returns three matches for the one record you have in table A. This increases your result set size to three records. Next, you join these three records with table C, on matching `ID`. Because all `ID`'s are, in fact, identical, this returns nine matches for every record in your current result set: you now have 9 x 3 = 27 records in your result set.

Finally, the `WHERE` clause comes into effect. This clause excludes 6 out of 9 records in table C, so you have 3 of those records left. Your final result set is therefore 1 (table A) x 3 (table B) x 3 (table C) = 9 records.